# What's the difference between VideoView and TextureView and Suraceview in android?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview, textureview

What's the difference between VideoView and TextureView and Suraceview in android?

And when do I use each one?

Comment: VideoView is just a wrapper around SurfaceView that plays videos. If you want the gory details, see https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late answer, just stumbled upon this but the TL;DR answer is this:

`VideoView` -> VideoView extends SurfaceView and is essence just SurfaceView + MediaPlayer. The dismantling of the surface and MediaPlayer and such is taken care of by the widget for your convenience.

`SurfaceView`-> According to Android Developer:

> Provides a dedicated drawing surface embedded inside of a view hierarchy. You can control the format of this surface and, if you like, its size; the SurfaceView takes care of placing the surface at the correct location on the screen
>
> The surface is Z ordered so that it is behind the window holding its SurfaceView; the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its surface to be displayed

What this means is that it takes info from the view hierarchy to create a dedicated drawing area hooked up to the GPU. The drawback of which means **no fancy view stuff such as animations and transitions**. But **more performant**

`TextureView` -> From Android Developer:

> Unlike SurfaceView, TextureView does not create a separate window but behaves as a regular View. This key difference allows a TextureView to be moved, transformed, animated, etc

And there you have it, the drawback of a TextureView means that, due to it being part of your view hierarchy, it will redraw it self during the view passes thus **costing more resources**, but you will have **animations, transitions, alpha etc.**